# How can I redirect old permalink structure to new permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Until recently the custom url structure was set like this:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%
```

and they were all located in the /blog/ subfolder.

Due to pagination issues I changed the permalink to the standard:

```
domain.com/sample-post/
```

What I'm wondering is, is there some way I can use htaccess to redirect from the old style to the new style? That way, any links to the old posts would go to the correct post? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your permalink structures you might like to look at Velvet Blues Update URL's Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: I was thinking more for potential redirects. If someone linked to the old post url i would like for them to be redirected to the new one to eliminate and 404s, etc.